# I get the following error whenever I try to run conda install tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

This is the error :

Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - numba -> numpy[version='>=1.14,<1.15.0a0']
  - tensorflow
Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

Comment: Are you trying to install tensorflow into an existing environment? What happens if you try to install it into a new one?

Comment: How can install tensorflow into a new enviroment?

Comment: `conda create -n mynewenv tensorflow` where *mynewenv* is the name you want to give it. If there are other packages you definitely want at the same time just add their names at the end of the command. Then you just need to `activate` that environment each time you want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to run the `conda info tensorflow` and `conda info numba` to see each dependencies for each package and then you have to install those package like `conda install package=version` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First create a conda environment if you would like using

```
conda create -n my_env python=3.6
```

Here "my_env" is the name of my environment

Then activate your environment using

```
source activate my_env #(for mac)
conda activate my_env #(for windows)
```

Once the Environment is active. you can now install the packages you need as follows:I am showing you the packages which i work upon on virtual environment and this will take care of most of your dependencies

```
conda update conda
conda upgrade conda
conda upgrade anaconda

conda update numpy    
conda install tensorflow
```

Hope this will solve your problem or else try to upgrade numpy using pip:

```
pip install --upgrade numpy
```