# Conda install tensorflow - Unsatisfiable error

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, nltk, conflict

I am trying to install tensorflow through Anaconda.
Unfortunately, I get following error:

[image]

I think nltk is a standard when installing Anaconda because I can't remember using it or installing it.
Now, all I want is to install TensorFlow but there seems to be a conflict.

Edit:

Uninstalling nltk resulted in the same error but with another package..
[image]

Comment: If you are not using nltk, then just uninstall it.

Comment: I'll try to do that. Although I do think it's a bit weird that they can't be installed together

Comment: This resulted in a new error:

Comment: Conflict: Anaconda-project, Tensorflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914882/i-get-the-following-error-whenever-i-try-to-run-conda-install-tensorflow