# conda: UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:

Tags: tensorflow, conda

I'm trying to install the current version of tensorflow which is 2.4 by this command in conda:

```
conda install tensorflow=2.4
```

but I got this error:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - py-opencv
  - tensorflow=2.4.1 -> tensorflow-base==2.4.1=eigen_py37h17880bf_0 -> h5py[version='>=2.10.0,<2.11.0a0'] -> hdf5[version='>=1.10.4,<1.10.5.0a0']
  - tensorflow=2.4.1 -> tensorflow-base==2.4.1=eigen_py37h17880bf_0 -> protobuf[version='>=3.14.0'] -> libprotobuf[version='>=3.14.0,<3.15.0a0']
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

When I installed it without specifying the version, it installed version2.0, while I want version 2.4.

Comment: Have you tried making a new environment instead? Also, confusing conflicts like this are often the result of mixing channels (e.g., **defaults** and **conda-forge**).

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914882/i-get-the-following-error-whenever-i-try-to-run-conda-install-tensorflow) reference may help you?